# SQL Server 2008 R2 Database Role Security Issue

Tags: database, membership, role

On a Sql 2008 R2 (10.50.4266) Windows 2008 R2 VM (VMware 5) server:
I am experiencing a strange problem.  It occurs off and on with no rhyme or reason.  When I go in and give a user or group a database role and then hit OK, I come back later and see that the check mark is no longer there.
The database role membership was never applied.  This has not just happened to me and it is not happening on other servers.  I have found nothing in Event logs, SQL Logs or Error Log.
Is anyony familiar with this bug/glitch/issue?